# Application Works in Debug but Not in Release on Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure

My application works fine in local debug but not on Azure Free Websites for one particular complex Action Result. My GlobalFilterException isn't even able to catch this bug (even if it works for all the other errors even in Release)... maybe because it's a problem with the server and not with my application ?

**Because the bug isn't catched by my Globalfilter, I have this browser error page :**

HTTP 500 Internal Server Error

- The website is under maintenance.
- The website has a programming error.

**I tried to activate logs on Azure and this is the last entry :**

FTP directory /LogFiles/http/RawLogs/ 
2014-12-10 02:03:08 myproject GET /email/sendemail - 0 - - - - - myproject 500 121 0 294 3525 229998

I see "500" in there... maybe it's again a clue about an Internal Server Error ?

**Where it crashes :**

It seems to crash in the middle of the ActionResult because after my foreach to send emails, I update my database with all the IDs of the sent emails. However, in release on Azure, nothing is updated in the database but some emails are sent.

This is the part where I'm pretty sure there's a bug :

```
try
{
        Parallel.ForEach(writeEmailViewModel.SelectedContactGroupIDs, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = maxParallelEmail }, selectedID =>
        {
            var destination = new Destination() { ToAddresses = (new List<string>() { companyContactGroups.First(s => s.ContactGroupID == selectedID).Contact.Email }) };
            var client = new AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient("***", "***", RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
            var from = "=?utf-8?B?" + System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(UserData.CompanyName)) + "?= <***>";
            var request = new SendEmailRequest(from, destination, message) { ReplyToAddresses = new List<string>() { writeEmailViewModel.ReplyToEmail } };
            var response = client.SendEmail(request);
            responseInfoList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(selectedID, response.MessageId));
        });
}
finally
{
        // Replace this with delivery notification
        foreach (var responseInfo in responseInfoList)
        {
            var emailCampaignContact = emailCampaignContactList.First(s => s.ContactID == companyContactGroups.First(r => r.ContactGroupID == responseInfo.Key).ContactID);
            emailCampaignContact.IsSent = true;
            emailCampaignContact.MessageID = responseInfo.Value;
            db.Entry(emailCampaignContact).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Showing the code of the particular action that is causing the 500 error would be a start.

Comment: Might be worthwhile adding a `catch` block in there, especially to be able to send some emails and fail others.  Exactly how many emails are being sent when this action is called and you see the error?  The log you posted shows that this is happening on a GET as opposed to a POST??

Comment: I didn't put a "catch" because I have my Global Exception Filter for this. But with this bug, my filter isn't even called... weird.. no ? And yes it's a get.. the user writes his email, then there's a confirmation page. Nothing is posted to this ActionResult (I use a TempData to fill writeEmailViewModel). And it works with 200 emails more or less.... but with more than 300 emails it crashes on Azure (however it still works in debug). Could it be something with an execution timeout ? Before the try-finally, I do a lot of validations, and it takes a lot of time and loading…

Comment: My guess is that your GET is timing out before is completes sending of the emails.  I believe that the default execution timeout is 110 seconds, and sending 300 emails (especially when calling out to an external service) I could see this exceeding the timeout.

Comment: Any reasons why it works in debug but not in release ? I already have a super high maxRequestLenght (40000) and executionTimeout (10000), any other place where Azure could overide this value ?

Comment: When you say that it works in debug mode, are you also running it locally?  And with the same volume?  I would look at queuing these requests, and having them processed by a worker role instead.

Comment: Yes. In debug and in local with the same volume. I like the idea of queuing this, but is it possible to do a worker role with Azure Websites free ? Any tutorial on this ?

Comment: You could try the azure webjobs to send this

Comment: My thought is that since you said it works for ~200 emails sent but not for 300 or more, you are probably being throttled by the "Free" web hosting plan you are deployed to.  The Free plan has some quota constraints that you are likely bumping up against.  Try it in Basic or Standard and see if the problem continues.

Comment: I'll try these suggestions thanks.